# Jquery get input hidden value not working

Tags: jquery, siblings

I am trying to get the value of a hidden input type, but it's not working.

JQUERY (in script tags):

```
$('.flagComment').click(function() {
    var commentid = $(this).siblings('.commentId').attr('value');

    alert(commentid);
});
```

HTML (this echos several times in a while loop):

```
<div class='bar'>
    <a href='#' class='flagComment'>Flag</a>
</div>

<input type='hidden' class='commentId' value='testvalue' />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
var commentid = $(this).parent().next('.commentId').val();
```

since the hidden input is a sibling of the div, and not the anchor.

Answer (score 0):

This should work better, because `.commentId` is not a sibling of `.flagComment`:

```
$('.flagComment').click(function(){
    var commentid = $(this).parent().next('.commentId').val();
    alert(commentid);
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FcbGH/)

Comment: `Closest` travels up the DOM, so it wouldn't find the next `.commentId`.

Comment: @john, what are you talking about?

Comment: You just changed `closest` to `parent`. Now it'll work. When you had it at `closest` it wouldn't work. Which is why, I imagine you changed your answer to `parent`.

Answer (score 0):

input is not a sibling for this link. Now it works:

```
<div class='bar'>
<a href='#' class='flagComment'>Flag</a>
<input type='hidden' class='commentId' value='testvalue' />
</div>
```

You can try also with closest() function:

```
$('.flagComment').click(function() {
    var commentid = $(this).closest('.commentId').attr('value');
    alert(commentid);
});
```